# Can an Indian National with a 2 year visa travel to UK if passport expires in 4 months?

Tags: uk, passports, indian-citizens

I am an Indian National. I have a valid 2 year UK visa and have been to the UK on 2 occasions in the previous year (stay of approx. 20 days). My passport is set to expire in 4 months. Can I still travel to the UK for a duration of 1 week now?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can travel. Your passport needs to be valid throughout your stay in the UK. There is no requirement for it to be valid beyond that.

> You must have a valid passport to enter the UK. It should be valid for the whole of your stay.

[gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk)

But if there is any transit country in between that can have its own rules.